# Saving project on Google Drive when using Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, adt, google-drive-api

Is there a way to save projects on Google Drive when using Android Studio?
I want to access the project from two different locations, but the path to my account under "users" is different, as I use two different usernames on each of the machines.

Since Google Drive folder is under my user folder, the config is wrong if the project is opened from the other machine.

Any advise how I can use the cloud to work on my project?

Thanks!

Comment: You should use a versioning system in such case like Git! Android Studio has many solutions github and bitbucket integration

Answer (score 0):

Trying to use a networked folder to access from two different machines is problematic -- At a minimum, you'll be trying to share **local.properties** files between the instances, which it's specifically intended to not do. The **.idea** and **.iml** files, if you're using Gradle-based projects, aren't intended to be shared among computers. I've seen reports that these can contain absolute paths, which will make sharing them tricky. That's perhaps a bug that could be fixed, but we treat those files as local in Gradle-based projects and not intended to be checked into source control, for example.

I think that's your answer -- set up your project in source control and use that to use it from multiple places. You'll lose the ability to be able to access the project in the exact same in-progress state from multiple places and will need to commit your changes first, but that can sometimes be an advantage, too. The saving of commit history may also be a big benefit -- it's one of those things that sometimes comes in really, really handy when you get your project in a bad state and just want to hit the reset button. Granted, Android Studio has local file history (which is a great feature, but is machine-local), but source control is more resilient.

Comment: Is it not possible to have the gradle stuff out side of Google Drive and just have the app folder inside Google Drive?